# A faster way to solve $\frac1{x^2+6x-15}+\frac2{x^2+6x+3}=\frac3{x^2+6x+1}$ in a timed test?

Tags: fractions, rational-functions

What is a faster way to do this problem?

> Solve the equation $$
> \frac{1}{x^2+6x-15} + \frac{2}{x^2+6x+3} = \frac{3}{x^2+6x+1}
> $$

This is from a timed test, so the fastest answers would be the best.
I know the old reliable way is just to multiply the denominators, but I'm pretty sure there is a faster way.

Comment: What have you tried? Hmm???

Comment: @Riemann'sPointyNose It literally says it in the question: multiplying the denominators

Comment: Ah yes, so it does xD

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing that comes to my mind is to let $y = x^2 + 6x + 1$.  Then $$\frac{1}{y-16} + \frac{2}{y+2} = \frac{3}{y}.$$  Then solve for $y$, and then solve the quadratic for $x$.

Comment: This was going to be my suggestion. Worth noting: since the numerators on the left sum to the numerator on the right, the $y^2$ terms will cancel.

Answer (score 3):

If $y=x^2+6x+9$ (I chose $9$ because $x^2+6x+9$ is a perfect square), then your equation becomes$$\frac1{y-24}+\frac2{y-6}=\frac3{y-8}.\tag1$$But$$\frac1{y-24}+\frac2{y-6}-\frac3{y-8}=\frac{12y}{(y-24)(y-6)(y-8)}$$and therefore the only root of $(1)$ is $0$. So, since $x^2+6x+9=(x+3)^2$, the only root of your equation is $-3$.

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite it as

$$\frac1{(x+3)^2-24}+\frac2{(x+3)^2-6}=\frac3{(x+3)^2-8}$$

and notice that $\frac1{24}+\frac26=\frac9{24}=\frac38$. If you don’t notice that (and it really is worth trying $x=-3$, just on spec), you can let $y=x+3$, rewrite as

$$\frac1{y-24}+\frac2{y-6}=\frac3{y-8}$$

and solve fairly quickly:

$$\frac{3y-54}{y^2-30y+144}=\frac3{y-8}\,,$$

$$\frac{y^2-26y+144}{y^2-30y+144}=1\,,$$

and $y=0$.